# What is the inverse of $G: (x,y) \rightarrow (x, 1-ye^x+xe^y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function

How can I calculate the inverse of
$$
\begin{align*}
G: \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\\
(x,y) &\mapsto (x, 1-ye^x+xe^y)
\end{align*}
$$
I actually just need the inverse in a neighborhood of the point $(0,1)$, and I know that the inverse exists in that neighborhood because
$$
[D_pG] = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
-ye^x+e^y & xe^y-e^x
\end{matrix}\right)_p 
\implies
[D_{(0,1)}G] = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
e-1 & -1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
which is invertible, and by the inverse function theorem I know that there is $G^{-1}:U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $G(0,1) \in U$ open set.

---

Here's what I was able to achieve:

One thing to note is that when $v \rightarrow 0$ we have that

$$
G^{-1}(v) \sim D_{(0,0)}G^{-1}(v) + G^{-1}(0,0)
$$

But $G^{-1}(0,0) = G^{-1}(G(0,1)) = (0,1)$  and $D_{(0,0)}G^{-1} = D_{G(0,1)}G^{-1} = (D_{(0,1)}G)^{-1}$, therefore we can conclude that when $v \rightarrow 0$ it follows that

$$
G^{-1}((v_1,v_2)) \sim (D_{(0,1)}G)^{-1}((v_1,v_2)) + (0,1) = (v_1,-v_1-v_2+v_1e+1)
$$

Can someone please check my work and give me some directions?

Thanks!